# JRE reinstallation error - Cannot install or upgrade any package

Tags: package-management, jre

This error occurs everytime I try to install or check for updates. I simply cannot do anything.

```
E:The package jre1.8.0-66 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: You could try to remove that package using `sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq jre1.8.0-66`. If it worked, tell me and I convert this comment into an answer.